# PHP programing print constant value using scope resolution operator with class

Tags: php

I want to print constant value in PHP by scope resolution operator, but it is echo this : `$p=new Ninja(); echo $p->show();`

Please note that I have just started to learning so there could be mistakes....

```
   <html>
      <head>
        <title>Scope it Out!</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <p>
          <?php
            class Person {                  
            }
            class Ninja extends Person
            {
              const stealt="MAXIMUM";
              function show()
              {         
                echo Ninja::stealth;        
              }
            }
         ?>
          $p=new Ninja();
          echo $p->show();
        </p>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: You will not able to directly access the scope resolution operator constant variable. assign the method name to class name with scope resolution operator then only it's member is accessed                                                                   more details see the url                                                                                                http://phppot.com/php/php-scope-resolution-operator/

Answer (score 3):

1. Correct your spelling for stealth.
2. `Ninja::stealth;` should be `self::stealth`
3. NEVER put a class definition along with HTML. Create a separate class file and include it.
4. `$p=new Ninja();` and `echo $p->show();` are outside PHP tags.

Comment: what is self here ??

Comment: when you are referring constant inside the same class, you should call it as `self::stealth`. If you are calling it outside the class, then you use `Ninja::stealth`.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Person {
}

class Ninja extends Person
{
    const stealt="MAXIMUM";

    function show()
    {
       echo Ninja::stealt;   // spelling mistake here..
    }
}
//remove php closed tag from here...

$p=new Ninja();
echo $p->show();
```